# How to get the importing file's path in Python (if __name__ == __main__ and Pytest)

Tags: python, import, module, pytest

I found quite a lot of answers about imported files (modules).

However, how can I get the name of the *importing* file from within a module?

My motive is driven by Pytest'ing a file (that is imported by a test-file) that has the `if __name__ == __main__` condition, that prevents the execution of its code from the test-file.

The idea is to expand the condition into something like:
`if __name__ == __main__ or 'test' in __importing_name__`

Is this a recurring issue with Pytest? What would be the best practice to handle it?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Without an explicit and minimal example is hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

A module can tell which module imported it by using the `__main__` module:

```
import __main__
if hasattr(__main__, '__file__'):
    print 'The module %s imported me' % __main__.__file__
```